# Show mini and max dates for highlighting in jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

To select a date range, I use the Jquery UI Datepicker plugin. I use a code that shows the number of days when choosing a period.

To connect the plugin, I use CDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>       
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://jquery-ui-bootstrap.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"></link>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <h3>From:</h3>
    <input id="from" type="text" name="from" readonly />
</div>
<div>
    <h3>To:</h3>
    <input id="to" type="text" name="to" readonly />
</div>
<div>
    <span>You have chosen:</span>
    <span id="days"></span> days.
</div>
```

Plugin Initialization:

```
var from = new Date();
var to = new Date();
var dayDiff = 1;

$(function() {
    var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: 14,
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                                    selectedDate, instance.settings);
                    dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);

                    if (this.id == "from") {
                            from = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                            if (!(to == "")) {
                                    update_days()
                            }
                    }
                    if (this.id == "to") {
                            to = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                            update_days()
                    }
            }
    });
});

function update_days() {
    dayDiff = Math.ceil((to - from) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $("#days").empty()
    $("#days").append(dayDiff)
}
```

How to make a dynamic selection of days?

For example, the user clicked on April 1st. Shows only 14 days that he can choose. If the user clicked on April 7th, also shows 14 days that can choose.

In both cases, this is minDate: 0, and maxDate: 14,

---

I found a similar code, only here it prohibits the allocation of the next 7 days:

```
let counter = 0;
let selected;

const calendar = $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    range: true,
    toggleSelected: false,
    multipleDatesSeparator: " - ",
    multipleDates: false,
    onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst) {
            selected = date;
            // console.log(selected[0])
    },
    // onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {
    //   if (selected) {
    //     const difference = Math.ceil((date - selected[0]) / 1000 / 3600 / 24);
    //     console.log(difference)
    //     if (difference < 7 && difference > -7) {
    //       return {
    //         disabled: true
    //       }
    //     }
    //   }
    // }
}).data('datepicker');

const test = function(date, cellType) {
    if (selected) {
            const difference = Math.ceil((date - selected[0]) / 1000 / 3600 / 24);
            console.log(difference)
            if (difference < 7 && difference > -7) {
                    return {
                            disabled: true
                    }
            }
    }
}

calendar.update('onRenderCell', test)
```

Need your help! Thanks!